# How to unzip file and copy database from it in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, unzip

i am newbie and first to try unzip file, i want to unzip my database contain file and copy database from it for this i try like as

In my `DBManager.m`  file i write like as

```
@interface DBManager()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentsDirectory;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseFilename;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrResults;

@end

-(instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;
    [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
}
return self;
}
```

For unzip file I write like as,

```
#pragma mark - Private method implementation
-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory
{
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampledb.zip"];

NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.documentsDirectory];

ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

if( [za UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath] )
{
    if( [za UnzipFileTo:output overWrite:YES] != NO )
    {
        NSLog(@"Archive unzip success");
    }

    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}
NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath])
{
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
}
```

And in my `ViewController` class `ViewDidLoad` I write code for copy database like as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"sampledb.sql"];
}
```

But my Database is not copied from zip file Please give me solution for it.
Here `sampledb.zip` is my zip file and `sampledb.sql` is my database file in my zip file. i use `ZipArchive` from github to unzip file.

Comment: Is that you getting the unzip file path ?

Answer (score 1):

As a minimum

`NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.documentsDirectory];`

should be

`NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampledb.sql"];`

If the source of the sql zip file is the bundle, you shouldn't need to zip the database file as Xcode will zip it when adding it to the bundle.